# PlayFramework memory setting options are not respected

Tags: java, bash, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a Play Framework application that I want to run on production mode but whenever I run `activator start -mem 512`  or `activator start -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx512m` I get errors about JVM not being able to allocate enough memory. The odd thing is that error logs indicate that arguments passed on to jvm was:

`-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -Duser.dir=/home/oguz/dev/rhymo-server/target/universal/s$`

but when I print the command information from the activator bash script I get:

`java -Dactivator.home=/home/oguz/frameworks/activator-1.2.12 -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -jar /home/oguz/frameworks/activator-1.2.12/activator-launch-1.2.12.jar start`

It seems that play is running the right command but somewhere along the lines the arguments get discarded. What is wrong here? Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are facing a [bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3688) in Activator. You can work around it using `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
$ JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m" ./activator start
```

or add an alias to this to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`. Also you can run `activator stage` and then start your app using

```
$ target/universal/stage/bin/YOUR-APP-NAME -mem 512
```